# Eliminate all duplicates except NA values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to eliminate all duplicates except `NA` values.

I Have this File:

```
Name weight
John .  10
John .  12
NA .    12
NA .    12
NA .    13
Peter . 15
Andy .  16
Clark . 17
```

And I need this:

```
Name weight
 NA .    12
 NA .    12
 NA .    13
 Peter . 15
 Andy .  16
 Clark . 17
```

I tried this code:

```
New.dt=dt[!(duplicated(dt$Name) | duplicated(dt$Name, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

But I can this:

```
Name weight
Peter . 15
Andy .  16
Clark . 17
```

And I want to keep the `NA` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
New.dt=dt[!(duplicated(dt$Name) | duplicated(dt$Name, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
dt2 = dt[dt$Name = is.na(dt)]
rbind(New.dt, dt2)
```

Comment: You could put it all together in one go I think - `x[(!(duplicated(x$Name) | duplicated(x$Name, fromLast=TRUE))) | is.na(x$Name),]`

Comment: I like it! Though I am more of a multi line kind of coder, and I want to start from where his/her attempt ended :)

Answer (score 1):

The double-tap of `duplicated` is faster (I thought `duplicated` would be slightly less-efficient with larger data), I suggest you go with that answer.

My answer is kept for the record.

---

One problem with using `duplicated` is that it will never remove all duplicates, since one it removes all but one of them, it is no longer duplicated.

A one-liner:

```r
x[ !x$Name %in% names(Filter(c, table(x$Name, useNA = "no") - 1)), ]
#    Name weight
# 3  <NA>     12
# 4  <NA>     12
# 5  <NA>     13
# 6 Peter     15
# 7  Andy     16
# 8 Clark     17
```

Explanation:

- `table(x$Name, ...)` will give you a named vector with the count of each element within the `Name` column;
- and though it is the default, I'm adding `table(..., useNA="no")` to be explicit, this means that `NA` values are not included in the returned vector of counts (thereby meeting your *"except NA values"* constraint);
- `Filter(c, ...)` filters the named vector based on a truthy-value of the contents, where "0" is considered non-truthy (and therefore removed) ... but since `table` will always return 1 or more (because it has to find one to include it in the list), ...
- I do `table(...) - 1` to reduce all singles (count of 1) to 0, so that the `Filter(c,...)` part can work;
- `names(...)` returns the `Name` values that have an effective count of 2 or more; and
- `!x$Name %in% ...` does the actual removal.

---

Data

```r
x <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Name weight
John    10
John    12
NA      12
NA      12
NA      13
Peter   15
Andy    16
Clark   17")
```

Comment: You could rejig this logic a bit maybe - `x[!(x$Name %in% na.omit(x$Name[duplicated(x$Name)])),]` to speed it up potentially

Comment: True, not sure how worth it is to squeeze a microsecond or two out. \*shrug\*, thanks @thelatemail.

Comment: Just think of the productivity gains - if you save 2 milliseconds a day, that's 3/4s of a second you have up-your-sleeve at the end of the year!

Comment: And after 13 years 4 months ... that'll give me one more "snooze" in the morning. \*Hrmph\*